# How to configure ArcGIS JS API 4.19 to use self-hosted ArcGIS Server GeometryService for Locate widget?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry-service

I'm using the Locate widget in my MapView using a self hosted 4.19 version. I followed the installation instructions but I just found out that it access arcgisonline.com to query the GeometryService REST API. I have a working ArcGIS Server with all the layers and services I need. How can I configure it to use my own GeometryService URL? Do I need to write my own Locate widget?

```
const locate = new Locate({
  view: view,
  useHeadingEnabled: false,
  goToOverride: function (view, options) {
    options.target.scale = 1500;
    return view.goTo(options.target);
  }
});
view.ui.add(locate, "top-left");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can override API defaults using the config module described in the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-config.html#geometryServiceUrl).

```
import esriConfig from "@arcgis/core/config";
esriConfig.geometryServiceUrl = "https://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer";
```

I would recommend setting fontsUrl too.

```
esriConfig.fontsUrl = "https://myserver.com/fonts";
```